# Preventing Node-red with postgres from escaping strings

Tags: postgresql, node-red

I have a Postgres node in a flow that inserts URL records. I am trying to prevent escaping them as I need the original URL.

```
INSERT INTO links (id,url,created_at, updated_at) 
VALUES (1,'{{msg.url}}','05/08/2020','05/08/2020');

It creates this in the database:
http:&#x2F;&#x2F;abc.com&#x2F;abcdxc&#x2F;doc&#x2F;doc&#x2F;processing.html
```

I need the URL unescaped in the database so I can query for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 `{`  rather than 2 in the Mustache template

```
INSERT INTO links (id,url,created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1,'{{{msg.url}}}','05/08/2020','05/08/2020');
```